# Find differences in name-value pairs across version IDs

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table with 3 columns:`version_id`, `name`, `value`.

Conceptually, this table has a bunch of name-value pairs for each `version_id`.

**How can I write a query that will show only the name value pairs of the top two version_ids where the name value pair is not the same across version-ids?**

Additionally, I am wondering if there is a way to put the differing name-value pairs from the different version_ids side by side, or have the rows be right next to each other in the results.

Basically, I want like a diff of the two versions.

Example:

```
version_id    name            value
  23459    jsLibrary2     JQuery_1_4_3
  23459    jsLibrary1     CrossDomainAjax_1_0
  23456    jsLibrary2     JQuery_1_4_2
  23456    jsLibrary1     CrossDomainAjax_1_0
  23456    groovyInclude2 GroovyUtilities
  23454    jsLibrary2     JQuery_1_4_2
  23454    jsLibrary1     CrossDomainAjax_1_0
  23454    groovyInclude2 GroovyUtilities
```

Ideal query result:

```
23456 jsLibrary2     JQuery_1_4_2
23459 jsLibrary2     JQuery_1_4_3
23456 groovyInclude2 GroovyUtilities
23459 NULL           NULL
```

Note that ideally it would note new name-value pairs (where the name doesn't exist in the smaller version_id) and deleted name-value pairs (where the name doesn't exist in the larger version_id)

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Comment: have you tried :   select version_id,name,value 
    from tablename 
    group by concat(name," ",value )

Comment: Why is groovyInclude2/GroovyUtilities in your ideal query result? that didn't change (name,value) across versions? And why is there that `NULL,NULL` line?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Because the name-value pair doesn't exist in the latest version.  It got deleted.  So it would be best if that could be represented in the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this can be simplified — or at least, I really hope it can — but:

```
SELECT name,
       version_id_before,
       ( SELECT value
           FROM property_history
          WHERE name = t.name
            AND version_id = version_id_before
       ) AS value_before,
       ( SELECT MIN(version_id)
           FROM property_history
          WHERE version_id > version_id_before
       ) AS version_id_after,
       ( SELECT value
           FROM property_history
          WHERE name = t.name
            AND version_id =
                 ( SELECT MIN(version_id)
                     FROM property_history
                    WHERE version_id > version_id_before
                 )
       ) AS value_after
  FROM ( SELECT name,
                CASE WHEN EXISTS
                           ( SELECT 1
                               FROM property_history
                              WHERE name = ph1.name
                                AND version_id =
                                     ( SELECT MAX(version_id)
                                         FROM property_history
                                     )
                           )
                     THEN ( SELECT MAX(version_id)
                              FROM property_history ph2
                             WHERE NOT EXISTS
                                        ( SELECT 1
                                            FROM property_history
                                           WHERE name = ph1.name
                                             AND version_id = ph2.version_id
                                             AND value =
                                                  ( SELECT value
                                                      FROM property_history
                                                     WHERE name = ph1.name
                                                       AND version_id =
                                                            ( SELECT MAX(version_id)
                                                                FROM property_history
                                                            )
                                                  )
                                        )
                          )
                     ELSE ( SELECT MAX(version_id)
                              FROM property_history
                             WHERE name = ph1.name
                          )
                 END AS version_id_before
           FROM property_history ph1
          GROUP
             BY name
       ) AS t
 WHERE version_id_before IS NOT NULL
;
```

(Disclaimer: tested only using your example data-set, for which it gives the result:

```
+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
| name           | version_id_before | value_before    | version_id_after | value_after  |
+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
| groovyInclude2 |             23456 | GroovyUtilities |            23459 | NULL         |
| jsLibrary2     |             23456 | JQuery_1_4_2    |            23459 | JQuery_1_4_3 |
+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I haven't made any effort to construct other data-sets to test it on.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a couple of subqueries to get the desired results since you are looking for the first and second values.  I'm assuming that the name is the 'key' that you have to group on, in which case something along these lines should work:

```
Select
     firstVersion.firstVersionId,
     firstVersionDetails.name as firstVersionName,
     firstVersionDetails.value as firstVersionValue,
     --second version values will be null if there is no second value
     secondVersion.secondVersionId, 
     secondVersionDetails.name as secondVersionName, --always the same as firstVersionName because name is a key field
     secondVersionDetails.value as secondVersionValue
From
     ( 
           Select 
                name, 
                Max(version_id) as firstVersionId
           From versions
           Group by name
     ) as firstVersion 
     join versions as firstVersionDetails--inner join because every name has a first version
          on firstVersions.version_id = firstVersion.firstVersionId
     left outer Join --outer join so we always get the first version and get the second version whenever there is one (in other words, does *not* limit data to names with at least 2 versions)
     (
           select 
                name, 
                Max(version_id) as secondVersionId
           from versions
           Group by name 
     ) as secondVersion
         on firstVersion.name=secondVersion.name
         and secondVersion.version_id < firstVersion.firstVersionId  --exclude the first version when calculating the 'max'.  This is the part of the join that allows us to identify the second version
     left outer join versions as secondVersionDetails --using outer join again so we don't limit our data to names with 2 versions
          on secondVersion.secondVersionId = secondVersionDetails.version_id
```

Happy querying! :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach -

```
SELECT MAX(version_id) INTO @cur FROM tbl;
SELECT MAX(version_id) INTO @prev FROM tbl WHERE version_id < @cur;

SELECT name, @prev, MAX(IF(version_id = @prev, value, '')) AS prev_val, @cur, MAX(IF(version_id = @cur, value, '')) AS cur_val
FROM tbl
WHERE version_id IN (@prev, @cur)
GROUP BY name
HAVING cur_val <> prev_val;
```